# Deleting file from HDFS bypassing Trash using Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to delete HDFS file using Java. As my file size is greater than Trash limited configured I am not able to perform delete operation. Below is the code snippet used for file deletion. I know there is skipTrash option available in HDFS shell commands. Please let me know if anything similar is available in Java which will bypass Trash while deleting files.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;

hdfs.delete(output, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's kinda late but it might help someone else.

I was trying to figure this same thing and it wasn't easy to find the answer in documentation or anywhere else. Basically, if you use the code you've provided (which I will fill in for clarity), **I believe the trash is skipped and the files are simply deleted from HDFS** (recursively in this specific example).

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);

boolean recursive = true;
hdfs.delete(pathToFiles, recursive);
```

**If you want to move the files into trash, it seems you have to do so before the deletion.** For this, you'll want to something like this:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Trash;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;


FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
boolean skipTrash = false;

if (!skipTrash) {
    Trash trashTmp = new Trash(hdfs, configuration);
    trashTmp.moveToTrash(pathToFiles);
}
hdfs.delete(pathToFiles, recursive);
```

Remember to handle IOException that might be thrown by this operation.

I found this example on JavaSED (Sources, Examples, Discussions): http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.fs.Trash. There are more examples showing the usage of Trash and deletion, so check it out.